# Using syntax highlighter with Tumblr

Tags: blogs, tumblr

I'm trying to use [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) with my blog at http://a.shinynew.me.  This is a tumblog.

I cannot seem to get it to work.  I have followed his basic instructions for installation using the CDN hosted versions, but nothing happens on the page and nothing gets thrown in either firebug or chrome dev tools.  All referenced resources are loaded.

I was hoping someone could clue me in to how to use [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) with Tumblr, and if not, what a suitable alternative might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try this.](http://drnicwilliams.com/2007/03/08/syntax-highlighting-in-tumblr/)

Comment: I did see that, and I'm not opposed to it - i'm just partial to syntax highlighter because it's so graceful.  I'll see if I can have a go with it.

Comment: This solution is the only one I have found to work so far, so I'm going with it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to switch the answer on this to a better answer which is Gist from GitHub.  Embeds perfectly with beautiful syntax highlighting and minimal markup.

https://gist.github.com/